# How to configure `require` / `window.$mod.defined` path for convoy

Tags: node.js, ember.js, convoy

Anyone knows how to configure the way convoy does fill the `window.$mod.defined` object ?

Mine looks like:

```
{ 'project-name-dir/src/webapps/subproject-name/core': Object,
  'project-name-dir/src/webapps/subproject-name/main': Object,
  'project-name-dir/src/webapps/subproject-name/user_template': Object,
  'project-name-dir/src/webapps/subproject-name/user_view': Object,
  'ember/application': Object,
  'window/convoy-index': Object,
  ... }
```

This has some drawbacks:

- I can't use `require('core')`, I have to use `require('project-name-dir/src/webapps/subproject-name/core')`.
- It reveals the structure of the source code of my project and I'm a discreet person on that matter.

I see ember is able to use short names, but I would like - if that is possible - to keep the definition of the pipeline in another directory (namely: `controllers`) than the sources of the assets.

My pipeline is copied from the `contacts` sample included with `ember.js`, slightly modified:

```
var pipeline = convoy({
  watch: true,

  'project-name-dir/tmp/subproject-name/assets/app.js': {
    packager: 'javascript',
    compilers: {
      '.hbr':    require('ember/packager').HandlebarsCompiler,
      '.js':     convoy.plugins.JavaScriptCompiler,
      '.coffee': convoy.plugins.CoffeeScriptCompiler
    },
    main: './src/webapps/console_component_io/main.js',
    minify: (MODE === 'production')
  }
}
```